# Save binary file from base64 data in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to download xlsx spreadsheet with javascript. I have tested base64 data. I decode it like so:

`var data = atob(validBase64Data);`

After that, I do:

```
save(name, data, type) {
  const blob = new Blob([data], {type: type});
  let objectURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  let anchor = document.createElement('a');

  anchor.href = objectURL;
  anchor.download = name;
  anchor.click();

  URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL);
}
```

Where name is a filename.xlsx, data is the decoded data and type is a mime-type string.

The excel file is downloaded but would not open as excel. Data is corrupted somehow.

In addition: I tested the same data with a unix terminal command to base64 decode and write the xlsx directly into that file, and that produced working file. Test was done like so:

1. I saved base64 data to test_excel.txt`
2. Ran command `base64 -D -i test_excel.txt -o test_excel.xlsx`
3. test_excel.xlsx is recognized by excel.

What am I doing wrong with the code?

Comment: @RolandStarke I tested btoa, which, I assume, reverts atob with same Unix interface, and it worked.

Comment: Thinking about it further, my suspicion is now that the original file string was not utf-8-encoded, but `atob()` assumes `dataFromServer` was a base64-encoded string that came from a utf-8 encoded string.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts this is not relevant, after I receive it, I test it as I explain in my question.

Comment: What is the value of the type parameter?

Comment: @James I tried 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' and 'octet/stream'

Comment: @PatrickRoberts "I tested the same data with a unix terminal command to base64 decode and write the xlsx directly into that file, and that produced working file." I assume this excludes invalid data, right? Would you suggest I try to utf8 decode it anyway?

Comment: @DivisionbyZero I can read, thank you. I'm saying that your terminal-based base64 decoder generates a binary string, whereas `atob()` generates a utf-8 string. So no. If I am correct, your corrupted file will have a larger byte size than the valid file.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts done the edits you proposed.

Comment: Before I make an assertion that I'm correct, try running `base64` without `-i`. If that _doesn't_ work, then the problem is that your `atob()` isn't RFC 3548 compliant, which would have a different solution that is much simpler.

Comment: Your save function is fine - [quick fiddle using a xlsx file from the client](https://jsfiddle.net/fde3emas/) - so the data you're getting must be mangled a bit as @PatrickRoberts is suggesting.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts tried without `-i` option. Still works fine.

Comment: @James that's not really a good test. [This would be a more accurate test](https://jsfiddle.net/fde3emas/2/).

Comment: Can you propose a test to compare the data I produce with the one uploaded through the input?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Ah ok.  I was just trying to provide a code-based working example that could be used as a starting point to eliminate the parts that work.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code that solved it:

```
export default {
 save(name, data, type, isBinary) {
  if (isBinary) {
    var bytes = new Array(data.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    data = new Uint8Array(bytes);
  }

  var blob = new Blob([data], {type: type});
  let objectURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  let anchor = document.createElement('a');

  anchor.href = objectURL;
  anchor.download = name;
  anchor.click();

  URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL);
 }
}
```

Thanks to everyone who participated in resolving.
Also, credits to: [Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so let's clarify a few things before anyone tries to "explain" the problem incorrectly.

The original `.xlsx` is a binary-encoded file, meaning that the data will contain bytes in the full range of `0x00` to `0xFF`.

In the question, it is assumed that this string has been successfully encoded into a valid base64 string, **with no extraneous characters** (as indicated by the success of the test using `base64` without the `-i` flag), and stored to `validBase64Data`.

The problem is that `atob(validBase64Data)` generates a string decoded into utf-8, not binary. And as I said before, the original binary string contains non-ASCII bytes in the range `0x80` to `0xFF`. In utf-8, these code points are stored as two bytes instead of one, so the solution, as described in [Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript), is to convert the code points of each character in the utf-8 string `data` into bytes stored as a `Uint8Array`, and then construct a `Blob` from that.

A naive solution might look like this, though please refer to [Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript) for more performant solutions:

```
const blob = new Blob([Uint8Array.from(data, c => c.charCodeAt(0))], { type });
//...
```

This uses [`TypedArray.from(iterable, mapFn)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/from).